# How do I resolve "getTipElement() is not a function" error with Bootstrap Tour?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tour

I am trying to create a website tour for a company website. For that, I used the [Bootstrap Tour API](http://bootstraptour.com/). The problem arrives when a certain webpage (all coded similarly) obstructs the tour by the following error:

> getTipElement is not a function

I tried using different files in the bootstrap folder and linking them to the webpage but getting the same result.

```
Bootstrap Tour 'tour' | Scroll into view. ScrollTop: 0. Element offset: 15.5. Window height: 193. bootstrap-tour.js:461:31
TypeError: $element.data(...).getTipElement is not a functionbootstrap-tour.js:584:44
    _showPopover file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/clove/assets/js/bootstrap-tour.js:584
    _showPopoverAndOverlay file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/clove/assets/js/bootstrap-tour.js:540
    bind file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/clove/assets/js/bootstrap-tour.js:22
    _scrollIntoView file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/clove/assets/js/bootstrap-tour.js:656
```

The tour should seamlessly move through the webpages and end itself.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on downloading from the master branch. However, downloading from the source zip (bootstraptour.com -> Download) fixed the issue.

Discussed here -
https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/660

Edit - Still faced some issues. Switching to the normal version (not minified) resolved it